# How to start a command on bash in the screen by python

Tags: python, bash

I use `python 2.7` and `Django 1.11.5`.

I want to check that my process `manage.py`, running in screen. If check is false I want to start process `manage.py`.

I use three files: `check.py`, `start_screen.sh`, `start_server.sh`.

I check the process in the first file(`check.py`):

```py
import subprocess
from settings import BASE_DIR, SERVER

process_list = subprocess.check_output(['/bin/ps', 'ax'])
my_server = re.search('SCREEN .* server', process_list)
if my_server is None:
    s = subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', BASE_DIR + '/start_screen.sh'])
```

I start the screen in the second file(`start_screen.sh`) :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env bash
screen -dmS server /bin/bash /home/user/Desktop/python_server/start_server.sh
```

I start the server in the third file(`start_server.sh`):

```py
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/Desktop/python_server/
/usr/bin/python manage.py server 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I want to reduce the number of files to one python file.

Also I want to pass parameters like `SERVER.PORT`, `SERVER.ADDRESS` and `BASE_DIR` to the request.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to obtain?
From what I see I suspect that this is a script to start / stop Django but it doesn't seem something that you would like using for production.

Comment: I want to restart process in screen when(if) it falls. If you know other way to do this, it may be interesting for me. I want to make current code better and more `pythonic`.

Comment: @ДмитрийСиденко can't you use something like `if ! pgrep -f "screen.*start_server.sh"; then screen -dmS server /bin/bash /home/user/Desktop/python_shome/user/Desktop/python_server/start_server.sh; fi`? This way you don't have to invoke python script.

Comment: I have a variables like `SERVER.PORT`, `SERVER.ADDRESS` and `BASE_DIR`. I can get it only from my python script, so the best way is to call it from python as far as I see. In addition, I need to run multiple server instances and I need to change this variables in this script. But I am open to the opinions of others.

Comment: Sure thing... There are countless tutorials on the topic, I just link one here, I'd go - personal preference - with the Gunicorn part: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment

Comment: Thank you for information. I learn it and restruct the server later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank the participant [Pitto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509977/pitto) for help in improving the server.

I find the next way to solve the current problem.

```py
import subprocess
from settings import BASE_DIR, PYTHON_DIR, SERVER_PORT

process_list = subprocess.check_output(['/bin/ps', 'ax'])
my_server = re.search('SCREEN .* server', process_list)
if my_server is None:
    s = subprocess.check_output([
        "screen -dmS server && "
        "screen -S server -X -p 0 stuff 'cd {0}/\n' && "
        "screen -S server -X -p 0 stuff '{1} manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:{2}\n'"
        .format(BASE_DIR, PYTHON_DIR, SERVER_PORT)], shell=True)
```

If you want to start this screen from root you need to start python from root or make crontab with root. To configure crontab use:

```
crontab -e
```